# Libraries to model district heating systems with Modelica Dymola

Tags: modelica, dymola

I want to model a district heating system with Modelica Dymola.

Which libraries can be used to model consumers, heat source and district heating network?
 - typically used
 - open source or commercial

I would also appreciate tips on how to assemble a simple first model.

Comment: https://github.com/modelica-3rdparty/ has a good list of open source libraries. I guess Annex60 or BuildSysPro is interesting to you based on their description. I haven't used them myself though.

Comment: Annex60 is now continued as IBPSA Project1, the repository moved here: https://github.com/ibpsa/modelica-ibpsa Please follow all the links in there, too.

Comment: Thank you I will check that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a commercial, supported and industrially proven library to model district heating systems from Modelon, the Thermal Power Library, see http://www.modelon.com/products/modelica-libraries/thermal-power-library/. You can e.g. do optimization based scheduling of production units for district heating networks, and a lot more.

Answer (score 3):

The opensource library TransiEnt is also able to model distric heating networks. It is part of a research project. https://www.tuhh.de/transient-ee/en/download.html

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can look at the commercial libraries that are part of the Dymola product portfolio, I’m sure you can find a good match.